# fatal: Could not read from repository

Tags: git, bash, bitbucket

So I got a new laptop after my previous one died - and I'm now trying to push to a repository on Bitbucket, and have run into a multitude of errors.  All the guides on setting up SSH on Bitbucket seem to deal with Git Bash - I'm running Git Shell and some of the commands return lots of errors.  Here's some of the errors that I've been seeing and have no idea what to do with:

```
C:\Users\Tai\Desktop\SYCS136 [master]> git push origin master
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,131.103.20.167' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

C:\Users\Tai\Desktop\SYCS136 [master]> ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,131.103.20.167' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).


C:\Users\Tai\Desktop\SYCS136 [master]> ssh -v hg@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,131.103.20.167' (RSA) to the list of k
nown hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Tai/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).

C:\Users\Tai\Desktop\SYCS136 [master]> ps -e | grep [s]sh-agent
Get-Process : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'e' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -ErrorAction -ErrorVariable.
At line:1 char:3
+ ps <<<<  -e | grep [s]sh-agent
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Is there another guide I can look at to solve this issue or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your key is being denied by the server. You need to fix the authorized keys on your bitbucket account.

Comment: It looks like you didn't transfer your SSH keys from the old machine to the new one?  If you lost the keys you'll need to add them on the server side.

Comment: @JohnZwinck so I'll have to simply create new ones then? I don't have the old laptop anymore so should I just delete the old ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you lost your SSH keys from your old machine (you should back them up somewhere secure next time).  Your new machine already has an SSH keypair, it's just different from the old one, so you need to update your authorized keys on BitBucket.